# s3 upload permission denied on Ubuntu but not on Windows

Tags: amazon-s3

I am setting up an AWS S3 bucket to upload some files, after installing aws-cli on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10, and I have done the aws configure with the same credential I saved from IAM.

When I run simple s3 cp command, the files on Windows pc uploaded to my bucket without an error, but same command on Ubuntu will hit with access denied error, I have to enable permission on my bucket to everyone to read and write then only it works on Ubuntu.

Any idea why this happen?

The error shown was "upload failed: ./test to s3://test A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied